# Retrieving original user identity from web application

Tags: c#, web-services, credentials

**Summary of the question**: In ASP.net, if you use credentials to invoke a web service, how can you retrieve the original user logged in to the web application calling the web service?

**Explanation:**

We have a web application, invoking a web service. Both are ASP.NET, currently 2.0.

The user logs in to the web application (Windows authentication), but to call the web service we use specific credentials:

```
   proxy.PreAuthenticate = true;
   proxy.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);
```

From the invoked web service, if we access the identity attribute of the webservice class (`WebService.User.Identity`) it **gets the original user logged in**, not these credentials.

However, when switching to Federation Authentication and .NET 4 in the web service, now WebService.User.Identity retrieves the special credentials.

Summing up, invoking the same web method with the same credentials, WebService.User.Identity returns:

- .NET 2 + Windows authentication: original username of the logged in user
- .NET 4 + Federation authentication: credentials used in the method call

How can I change it to get the original user logged in in .NET 4 with federation authentication?

**EDIT:**
Some more information, in .NET 2 the server variables related to the user are:

- AUTH_USER: user logged in
- LOGON_USER: special user credentials
- REMOTE_USER: user logged in

And as I said, in .NET 4 the 3 server variables are the special user credentials.

Comment: What are the exact paths of the web application and the web service (you can replace the domain name for security reasons)?

Comment: They are hosted in the same server, IIS 7.5, they are called http://contoso.com/webinterface and http://contoso.com/webadminservice

Comment: In this case, have you checked the remarks on this page: [HttpWebRequest.PreAuthenticate Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.preauthenticate(v=vs.110).aspx)? Maybe you shouldn't set `proxy.PreAuthenticate = false;`.

Comment: Sorry, meant: you should set `proxy.PreAuthenticate = false;`

Comment: Thanks @Alex, but the result is the same. In the remarks it says _"If the authentication scheme does not support preauthentication, the value of this property is ignored."_. I'm not sure if Federated authentication supports preauthentication, and I couldn't find anything online

Answer (score 0):

Hi Can you give a try to below code to get the original logged in user:

```
        string serverVariable = Request.ServerVariables["AUTH_USER"].ToString();
        string[] authUser = serverVariable.Split('\\');
        string strUserName = authuser[0];
        string strDomain = authUser[1];
```

Comment: Hi @Rohit, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately that returns the special credentials as well.

I have tried all the following: User.Identity; User.Person; Context.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name; Context.Request.ServerVariables["AUTH_USER"].

And they all return the credentials of the call, instead of the original user

Comment: did you tried retriving the credentials before making the call to webservice I mean before setting the credentials to your proxy

Comment: If they are unassigned, I can't get the credentials because the object is not set to a reference. If I set proxy.UseDefaultCredentials = true; it is the web application dedicated account (the identity of the application pool). And I get a 401 returned from the web service, because it is not allowed to call the web service.